# No records found in AND Condition Oracle Sql Query

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have query in which I select records with data validation on table with AND Condition but only 1 Condition have no records so that it returns 0 rows. How to avoid this condition.

**Query:**

```
SELECT a.clientid, a.cnic_no, a.nrsp_status, b.projectid
FROM we_group_hof_k a, hof b
WHERE a.clientid IS NOT NULL
AND a.nrsp_status = 2
AND LENGTH(a.cnic_no) <=13
AND b.urn like '006%'
```

I found last Condition b.urn does not have 006%. So this query return 0 rows. I want if this condition have no records then show others records

**Updated query:**

```
INSERT INTO we_group_hof
(clientid, projectid, cnic_no, gendid, rid, mstatusid, village_id, ucid, cityid, disttid, nrsp_hofid, group_hof_id, nrsp_status, isenrolled
, cardstatus, dob, cardno)

SELECT a.clientid, a.cnic_no, a.gendid, a.rid, a.mstatusid, a.village_id, a.ucid, a.cityid, a.nrsp_hofid,
a.group_hof_id, a.nrsp_status, a.isenrolled, a.cardstatus, a.dob, LPAD(b.projectid,3,0), LPAD(b.disttid,3,0),to_char(max(b.cardno)+1)

FROM we_group_hof_k a, hof b
WHERE ((a.clientid IS NOT NULL
AND a.nrsp_status = 2
AND LENGTH(a.cnic_no) <=13
AND a.isenrolled = 'Y'
AND a.cardstatus = 'A'
AND a.dob <= sysdate
AND a.dob IS NOT NULL)
OR b.urn like '006%')
GROUP BY a.clientid, b.projectid, a.cnic_no, a.gendid, a.rid, 
a.mstatusid, a.village_id, a.ucid, a.cityid, b.disttid, a.nrsp_hofid, 
a.group_hof_id, a.nrsp_status, a.isenrolled, a.cardstatus, a.dob;
```

I tried with this query but this query did not execute and query executing not execute

Comment: with all columns?

Comment: what do you mean by show other records?

Comment: I need if other column have records then show their records If any column have no records then show other columns records who have records

Comment: I am not clear yet. Can you check the below query satisfies your need. `SELECT a.clientid, a.cnic_no, a.nrsp_status, b.projectid
FROM we_group_hof_k a, hof b
WHERE ((a.clientid IS NOT NULL
AND a.nrsp_status = 2
AND LENGTH(a.cnic_no) <=13)
OR b.urn like '006%')`

Comment: Thanks i have missed the brackets. I have updated

Comment: I updated my latest query please check

Comment: `disttid` is missing in the select statement and try to use `JOIN` between table `we_group_hof_k`  and `hof`

Comment: I used disttid in select statement with LPAD function after projectid column. Which I need to use Join Simple Join or any other Join

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear if this is exactly what you want, but it's likely that an `OR` condition with proper parentheses will help you in selectively filtering the needed records.

```
..
WHERE 
(     a.clientid IS NOT NULL
      AND a.nrsp_status = 2
   AND LENGTH(a.cnic_no) <=13
) 
OR b.urn like '006%'
```

Comment: @RamizTariq : The column expressions used in your select  should match exactly with those in `group by`,  apart from the aggregate function.  When you say *"query did not execute"* , it is not related to your original question and this answer solves the actual problem with  `AND` condition.